# Euler-Lagrange Single function of single variable with higher derivatives

Tags: calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem, euler-lagrange-equation

Here is the page on Wikipedia:

So it says the fixed boundary conditions for the function itself as well as for the first $n-1$ derivatives. You can fix the boundary points physically say $y(a)=a'$ and $y(b)=b'$ but what about for the derivatives?
For example for this problem from my lectures- 
[image: y'(0)=0]

We've fixed $y(0) =0$ for this diving board problem - where does $y'(0)=0$ come from?

Then in the variant where the swimmer holds the board up we fix the the other end of the board $x=L$ at a certain height so $y(L)=$ "whatever". We need 4 boundary condtions here where is the other? I assume by Wikipedia article that $y'(L)$ is something- is the other fixed boundary condtion but what is it- it's not mentioned in the notes...

Would appreciate any clarification of the ambiguity thanks...

Answer (score 1):

In beam theory, beam is modelled as line curve with some stiffness properties. As such in 2D it can be modelled as a continously differentiable curve. Usually a fixed end is made as a horizontal groove in the fixed wall whereby the curve (i.e. the beam) will remain tangent at the location of the horizontal groove. Therefore, $y'(0)=0$

The swimmer's arm can be taken a simple support which can't provide an external moment. Hence the bending moment at the other end must also be zero. Hence by dynamic considerations $y''(L) = 0$. Thus you have the four boundary conditions viz. $y(0) =0, y'(0)=0, y(L) = $"whatever"$, y''(L) = 0$.